# Scala parsing, how to go through what has been collected

Tags: scala, parsing

Using [scala parser combinators](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators/tree/master/src/main/scala/scala/util/parsing/combinator) I have parsed some text input and created some of my own types along the way. The result prints fine. Now I need to go through the output, which I presume is a nested structure that includes the types I created. How do I go about this?
This is how I call the parser:

```
GMParser1.parseItem(i_inputHard_2) match {
  case GMParser1.Success(res, _) =>
    println(">" + res + "< of type: " + res.getClass.getSimpleName)
  case x => 
    println("Could not parse the input string:" + x)
}
```

EDIT
What I get back from `MsgResponse(O2 Flow|Off)` is:

```
>(MsgResponse~(O2 Flow~Off))< of type: $tilde
```

And what I get back from `WthrResponse(Id(Tube 25,Carbon Monoxide)|0.20)` is:

```
>(WthrResponse~IdWithValue(Id(Tube 25,Carbon Monoxide),0.20))< of type: $tilde
```

Just to give context to the question here is some of the input parsing. I will want to *get at* `Id`:

```
trait Keeper
case class Id(leftContents:String,rightContents:String) extends Keeper
```

And here is `Id` being created:

```
def id = "Id(" ~> idContents <~ ")"  ^^ { contents => Id(contents._1,contents._2) }
```

And here is the whole of the parser:

```
object GMParser1 extends RegexParsers {
  override def skipWhitespace = false
  def number = regex(new Regex("[-+]?(\\d*[.])?\\d+"))
  def idContents = text ~ ("," ~> text)
  def id = "Id(" ~> idContents <~ ")"  ^^ { contents => Id(contents._1,contents._2) }
  def text = """[A-Za-z0-9* ]+""".r
  def wholeWord = """[A-Za-z]+""".r
  def idBracketContents = id ~ ( "|" ~> number ) ^^ { contents => IdWithValue(contents._1,contents._2) }
  def nonIdBracketContents = text ~ ( "|" ~> text )
  def bracketContents = idBracketContents | nonIdBracketContents
  def outerBrackets = "(" ~> bracketContents <~ ")"
  def target = wholeWord ~ outerBrackets
  def parseItem(str: String): ParseResult[Any] = parse(target, str)

  trait Keeper
  case class Id(leftContents:String,rightContents:String) extends Keeper
  case class IdWithValue(leftContents:Id,numberContents:String) extends Keeper
}
```

Comment: The result does not appear to contain any `Id`s, so there does not seem to be anything to get at. Maybe the `id` rule was never invoked (or it never succeeded on the given input) or you discarded its result in whichever rules call `id`.

Comment: I'm thinking that when the mapping (^^) is done `Id` will get put into the output. I just put the whole parser up in case you can see where I'm discarding. I could solve the problem, and it may even be the best way(but ?? not so functional as will need to use `var`) by storing `Id` etc when they are being created.

Comment: What's your input? It looks like it simply does not match the `idBracketContents` rule and goes into the `nonIdBracketContents` rule instead.

Comment: My mistake. You are right the input was pretty simple. I will alter the text to show two inputs and corresponding outputs. But my question was meant to be more general. How do I *get at* all of the contents of `$tilde`, both things I have created and other things which might be lots of `ParserResult[T]` or some such...

Comment: FYI: The class is called `~`, not `$tilde`, in Scala. It just prints as `$tilde` here because you're using Java reflection and `~` isn't a valid name in Java (unlike Scala).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parser created by the `~` operator produces a value of the `~` case class. To get at its contents, you can pattern match on it like on any other case class (keeping in mind that its name is symbolic, so it's used infix).

So you can replace `case GMParser1.Success(res, _) => ...` with `case GMParser1.Success(functionName ~ argument) => ...` to get at the function name and argument (or whatever the semantics of `wholeWord` and `bracketContents` in `wholeWord "(" bracketContents ")"` are). You can then similarly use a nested pattern to get at the individual parts of the argument.

You could (and probably should) also use `^^` together with pattern matching in your rules to create a more meaningful AST structure that doesn't contain `~`. This would be useful to distinguish a `nonIdBracketContents` result from a `bracketContents` result for example.

Comment: For the moment, or until I become more *pure functional* I am going to go with my idea of just saving the `Id` or whatever *in-situ*. I've already done the pattern matching so why do it again? (So why did I ask in the first place you might then say!). It would be good to know of a good example/reference for dealing with the output properly. Most of the documentation I've seen so far only concentrates on the parsing.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy The upside of creating your own data types instead of `~` would be that you can distinguish between `nonIdBracketContents` and `bracketContents` without having to look more deeply inside to see whether there's any `IdWithValue`s in there or not. And in a more complicated grammar, there will likely be cases where you can't distinguish the results from different rules at all if you only use `~`. As for dealing with the output "properly", that completely depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: By output I meant output from the first lexing stage. Does `~` really contain the whole parsed tree? Do people usually look inside `~` or do what I have done (now actually with FastParse), and simply have map functions off the side that create what you want to see.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy Yes, I figured that, but what do you want to do with it? Like do you want to evaluate it? Generate code from it? Generate some form of IR from it? And in either of those cases: what are the semantics of your language? "Does ~ really contain the whole parsed tree?" It contains the results of both operands of `~`. Anything that you ignore with `~>` or `<~` won't be contained. Nor will there be any information telling you which side of an `|` was picked. "Do people usually [...]?" People usually use `^^` to create a proper AST and then work with that from there.

Comment: I had some objects that needed to be sent/received over http (somehow involving Ajax), using Autowire and uPickle. I was determining the String representation but it was getting complicated to go from String -> Object, so I chose to use a parser. There are ways of doing this that use uPickle more, but in the end I tried this approach. So I'm already doing what people normally do!

Comment: @ChrisMurphy So what kind of objects do you want to send exactly? It seems to me like you could just create the appropriate object structure using `^^` and then just send that over the wire in the `Success(...) =>` case without doing any further processing on it (because you'd already have created it exactly like you want it). On a completely unrelated note, you probably want to be using `parseAll` unless you're okay with parsing valid prefixes of invalid strings.

Comment: They are Scala objects inside Scala case classes. uPickle is doing most of the work - I just recently created a nested structure inside an object that was already being sent across the wire. uPickle allows you to have your own implicits for reading and writing, and I was parsing inside a `upickle.default.Reader`. I am no longer using scala-parser-combinators but [FastParse](https://github.com/lihaoyi/fastparse) so using `~ End` at the end, which I imagine does the same job as `parseAll`.

Comment: What I would really like to do is not pattern match but use a higher order function. I could somehow _tag_ all the objects I create - say by them all having a common trait, then use say `collect` to on `~` to get them all. This way would be functional, and really I should not need to do the pattern matching - that would be doing that same thing twice.

Comment: Or any even better solution that would mean no vars and only one parse through would be for `parseItem` to create and fill up a collection that it returns. No need to think about the `~` let alone pattern match it.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy So what you want to send over the wire is a list of `IdWithValue` objects or something like, right? In that case you can just use `^^` (or whatever FastParse's equivalent of that is) to create that from the parser. That seems to be the easiest solution to me.

Comment: My issue is trying to think of a way to get rid of using vars altogether. But I have not come up with one. One day I'll work out a general, type-safe, one-parse, completely-functional way of using a parser-contaminator to extract an AST. If you know how tell me and I'll make up a problem that's simple enough that the answer can be in code.

Comment: FastParse's equivalent is map!

Comment: @ChrisMurphy I don't see why you'd need vars. If you can give me a concise specification (or an example input and output) of what you want the result to look like, I can give you an example scala-parser-combinator grammar (which you'd need to translate to fastparse yourself as I'm not familiar with it, but that should not be a problem), which produces exactly that result. The way I understood you so far, you want a list, but I'm not quite sure of what as you create values of different types at different points.